# How to relate two binding in wpf in c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a solution in C# with two proyects. The first proyect calls to the second and uses a value of its binding (EstadoVisibleTeclado).

But when I want to use this value whitin a label, It does not appeare.

For example, in the first proyect:

```
<Label  Grid.Column="0"  Visibility="{Binding EstadoVisibleTeclado}" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="30" Width="AUTO" Content="Dirección" Margin="0,8,0,9"/>
```

In the second proyect I am writing the property to use in the DataContext of this way:

```
public String EstadoVisibleTeclado
        {
            get { return _estadoVisibleTeclado; }
            set
            {
                _estadoVisibleTeclado = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("EstadoVisibleTeclado");
            }
        }
```

and in the constructor of this way:

```
public Teclado()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        EstadoVisibleTeclado = "Collapsed";
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
```

Someone knows ¿how to shared the binding between proyects?.

someone like this:

```
Visibility="{PROYECT2.NAMEXAML.Binding EstadoVisibleTeclado}"
```

Regards.

Comment: You cant just reference a Binding in the XAML. `Proyect2.NAMEXAML...`. If you would have to find the control object explicitly from the visual tree or the current assembly, then look for the Visibility property of the applicable Control. I feel you need to change the design in some manner, as you should not have those types of dependencies across projects.

Comment: I would also have to extract the DataContext from the Control to get the property. This seems very messy.

Comment: I have downloaded a virtual keyboard proyect in wpf, to use it, I have import the proyect to my solution. The problem is when i want to show the keyboard, to do it I have added a property named "EstadoVisibleTeclado"  in the cs file of the keyboar. Of this way when I call the keyboard and after is closed with a button, it change the value and disappear of the firts proyect change the value to visibility. It is only one value, my intention is do it with a String to related with a text in a textbox.

Comment: Could you not have a static class that instantiates the Keyboard from the code behind, given some conditions (like entering edit mode on a TextBox)? While i dont understand the scope of your project, i will say that i dont know of an easy way to do what you are asking, i also think there may be a better way than trying to extract and reference a binding in a seperate project.

Answer (score 0):

Estadivisibleeclado should not be a string.

Comment: Hi. Why do you say that?. I have changed the type String by a  boolean type which I have insert in the property "Content" of the label, but no happens nothing..

Comment: Visibility is an Enum type. Not a string or boolean.

Comment: I have used the property Visibility with String called the proyect of this way:

`<tecladoEnPantalla:Teclado  x:Name="t1"  Visibility="{Binding EstadoVisibleTeclado}" Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="0" Margin="-47,-343,-78,-92" Loaded="t1_Loaded" />`

And it works. I do not think that it is the problem. I need a solution to the first xaml calls the binding of the second.

Comment: Your teclado control probably does some string conversion. If you want to bind to another control you could name it and reference it in the binding with an element name